# Theme customization background image is not displayed on a smartphone

Tags: background, themes, actions-on-google

According to the AoG docs I have set up a custom background image to use as a sheme.
https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/rich-responses#customizing_your_responses

The background is showing properly in the simulator (Smartphone and Smart Display).
On real devices the background is only shown on a Smart Display.

I have already tried different images and change turned dark mode on and off, but neither way the custom background image is shown.

Does anybody experienced the same issue or habe a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Under the theme customization tab, you can provide an image for each type of mode (Landscape and Portrait).

For smart displays, the Landscape mode photo will be displayed.

For phones, the Portrait mode photo will be displayed.

Please ensure you have provided a Portrait mode photo to be displayed on phone devices.